# JavaScript namespacing with/whitout var

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I need to know the difference between:

```
Namespace = (function () { 
    return { 
        name: 'Module', 
        dep: ['d', 'a']
    };
})();
```

and

```
var Namespace = (function () { 
    return { 
        name: 'Module', 
        dep: ['d', 'a']
    };
})();
```

simple as that but i still don't understand.

Comment: [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I never omit it. If you leave off the the `var` keyword that variable becomes a global one if the variable is declared inside a function. This is because variables have function level scope in JavaScript. In the example you have given `Namespace` will be a global variable whether you use `var` or not because it is not declared inside of a function. You can test this theory out by adding `var` to the `Namespace` variable in example 1 below.

**Example 1:**

```
//I am a global variable with or without the var keyword because
//I am declared outside of a function.
Namespace = (function () { 
        return { 
            name: 'Module', 
            dep: ['d', 'a']
        };
})();


function test(){    

   Namespace = "I was changed because i have global scope";

}

//Run the test function to gain access to the global variable inside.
test();

//You will see that the value was changed by calling the test function 
console.log(Namespace);
```

Now if you put your `Namespace` variable inside a function as it is now it will still be a global variable without the `var` keyword. In the example below I have moved your `Namespace` variable inside of function added the `var` keyword to it to make it a non global function. If you remove the `var` keyword from the `Namespace` variable inside of the function in example 2 you will see that it will then be a global variable and the last `console.log(Namespace)` call in the script will print out the `Namespace` value from the `getNameSpace` function.

**Example 2:**

```
function getNameSpace(){

var Namespace = (function () { 
        return { 
            name: 'Module', 
            dep: ['d', 'a']
        };
})();


}

function test(){    

Namespace = "I have global scope even inside a function because I am missing the var keyword.";

}

test();

//print the value of the global variable Namespace
console.log(Namespace);

//call get nameSpace
getNameSpace();

//This will still print the value from the test function because the variable inside of
//get Namespace has local or function level scope because it has the var keyword.
console.log(Namespace);
```

Hopefully all this makes more sense now. If it doesn't let me know I will try and help. A good thing to remember is to always use the var keyword and if you don't want another part of a script to access the variable directly then put it inside of function(also known as a closure).

Comment: Awesome explanation Larry, thanks!

Comment: @JessicaManid Not a problem I know there are other answers out there but they are not always easy to step through if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

When you use var you create a variable in the current scope of the function.
Without var the variable will be created on the global scope which is usually bad.

Use var and always create your variables in a closed scope (which is not the global scope) unless you have a good reason not to do it.

Comment: that is true for non strict environment.